# Array of Arrays on PHP to Object on Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I have something like this on PHP:
`$val[January]={[Car]=3, [Bike]=2, [Moto]=5;} //for each Month...`

And I want to convert to Javascript object like this:

`fData=[
{label: 'January', Values:{Car:3, Bike:2, Moto:5}},
....
]`

Comment: What is your language ? Where do you want to re-format it ? in PHP ou in JS ? Your first array uses mixed format...

Comment: PHP to Javascript, my first array used mixed format because I don't know how I I could represent...xD other vision: `$val[jan][car]=3 or something like this jajaja

Comment: answered to format properly your PHP array, does the output fits your need ?

Comment: in future, please improve your question description http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok @Sylca sorry about the inconveniences :_(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First format your PHP array as you want it to look :

```
$val[] = array('label' => 'January', 
               'Values' => array('Car' => 3, 
                                 'Bike' => 2, 
                                 'Moto' => 5)
              );
$val[] = array('label' => 'february', 
               'Values' => array('Car' => 4, 
                                 'Bike' => 5, 
                                 'Moto' => 6)
              );
$encoded = json_encode($val);
```

it should output a structure like :

```
fData=[
    {"label":"January","Values":{"Car":3,"Bike":2,"Moto":5}},
    {"label":"February","Values":{"Car":4,"Bike":5,"Moto":6}},
    ...,]
```

Comment: Just to clarify, this answer should output the following string: `[{"label":"January","Values":{"Car":3,"Bike":2,"Moto":5}}]` with double quoted string properties and values. The `0:` property in the json example looks like a a typo.

Comment: @Darragh Indead, thanks, I edited answer after running the code to get real output :)